# Index of / вместо страниц сайта.

Tags: хостинг

Здравствуйте. Недавно я приобрёл хостинг, чтобы разместить на нём свой сайт. Как и положено, залил в необходимые папки файлы своего сайта, но, при попытке запустить установку скрипта, вместо страниц сайта открывается белая страница с надписью Index of /. У других людей сайт открывается корректно. Почему так происходит у меня?

Answer (score 1):

Если проблема только у Вас - значит нужно почистить кэш браузера.

Answer (score 0):

В корне каталога должен быть индексный файл index.html, либо index.php, если это php хостинг. 
Если это php хостинг и в корне есть файл index.php возможно нужно изменить права на файлы (обычно 755 или 750)

Answer (score 0):

И кэш и дефолтная страница - все варианты надо пересмотреть. Но еще лучше - ставьте **Wireshark**, запускайте trace (*Ctrl+E*), "заходИте" на сайт, ждите результата в окне браузера, переключайтесь на **Wireshark**, останавливайте trace (опять *Ctrl+E*), в фильтре наберите **http** и сбоку жмите кнопку **Apply**. Затем на первом же пакете правой кнопкой и там **Follow TCP Stream**.
В новом появившемся окне будет вам счастье.